# Read and display data from .txt file by clicking next

Tags: php, file

I've researched this but the only answer I get is to display all the text, or line by line. How can I display data from text file in blocks.

lets say this is in a text file and I want to display this

display this when clicked `next` because there's a new line between the two lines.

I'm doing this because I have paragraphs and I don't want to display the lines that match the input, but every paragraph, displaying next block when clicked `next`

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): show us your code!

Answer (score 0):

Well the fastest thing i could think of would be:

```
$file = file_get_contents('text.txt', true);

$preview= explode(PHP_EOL, $file);

echo $preview[0];
echo $preview[1];
echo $preview[2];
echo $preview[3];
```

As you already have the other part and didnt see the code, this may help

Comment: P.S. And $preview[1] and echo $preview[3]; will be the empty lines, so if in the NEXT function would be even better to add a if($preview<>"") kind of thing